# Calculate ch(0.2) to the nearest 0.01

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, hyperbolic-functions

Help me calculate ch(0.2) to the nearest 0.01. I tried to rewrite ch as a series but I still don't know how to evaluate it and what to do with factorial

[image]

Help me please. it's very important

Comment: $ch(x) = \sinh (x)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have received a naswer from impartialmale who explains a lot of things. So, I shall just focus on the details.

If you expand your formula, you have $$ch(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=x+\frac{x^3
   }{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^9}{362880}+\frac{x^{11}}{39916800}+...$$ Now, make $x=0.2$ in the above formula and compute the terms one after each other and add them up to have the partial sums. You will see when you need to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following theorem related to Dalambe' s criteria 
(see the reference: http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/~lriddle/apcalculus/approxSeries.pdf):

**Theorem** Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive decreasing sequence such that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L<1.
$$
Then

(1) If $\displaystyle\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ decreases to the limit $L$ then
$$
S_n+a_n\left(\frac{L}{1-L}\right)<S<S_n+\frac{a_{n+1}}{1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}.
$$
(2) If $\displaystyle\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ increases to the limit $L$ then
$$
S_n+\frac{a_{n+1}}{1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}<S<S_n+a_n\left(\frac{L}{1-L}\right).
$$
Here 
$$
S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n, \quad S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k,
$$
to calculate 
$$
ch(0.2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(0.2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$$